# Use nested_form gem but show no form to begin with, only link_to_add

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

[Nested Form](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form)'s default usage is this:

```
<%= f.fields_for :tasks do |task_form| %>
  <%= task_form.text_field :name %>
  <%= task_form.link_to_remove "Remove this task" %>
<% end %>
<p><%= f.link_to_add "Add a task", :tasks %></p>
```

But what if I want to start my view without the form – just the `Add a task` link?

From here, it would work as normal.

I just don't want user to see a blank nested form field when they first visit the page.

Perhaps the solution is obvious, but I can't find it.

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: I also want solution for this problem :(